# Two includes from the same folder. One works, one doesn't - PHP

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to do some includes in my PHP file. Both the files I'm trying to include do off course exist.

This one works:

```
include("/folder/subfolder/firstfile.php");
```

This one doesn't:

```
include("/folder/secondfile.php");
```

How is this possible, since both includes are coming from the same folder.....?

The errors I'm getting

```
Warning: include(/folder/secondfile.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in index.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/folder/secondfile.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in index.php on line 2
```

File structure

Root has `folder` in it. The includes are made from a file that is in another folder in the root.

Comment: could you upload a snapshot of the error that you are face and file structure, that may help answer your question

Comment: Sure. I edited my question. Hope this makes things clear for you.

Comment: and directory structure ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP extension is missing in the second `include()`.

```
include("/folder/secondfile");
```

Change to

```
include("/folder/secondfile.php");
```

Also make sure that it is in folder `folder`. If it is in `subfolder`, don't forget to include it to path like :

```
include("/folder/subfolder/secondfile.php");
```

Comment: That was just an error I made when posting the question. The actual file isn't called second file.php off course.

Comment: It is not in the subfolder. I wouldn't post this question without checking for these kinds of mistakes. I'm not that lazy....

Comment: @FrankKluytmans..That is not my fault. While posting a question you have to make sure you are posting it correctly.